# Will it damage my washing machine and tumble dryer to be left in a shed for storage

Tags: dryer, washing-machine, shed, storage, damage

I have a Miele washing machine and tumble dryer, each worth around £600, that I bought last year.

I just moved houses and my new already has a washing machine and dryer.

Would it be safe to wrap and put my washing machine and dryer in a Plastic Keter shed in my garden for a few years, or could the cold weather in the non-insulated shed damage them?

(Another option is to put them in my storage loft, but that is a real mission!)

Comment: Why not sell them and then in a few years if you need to buy a new *used*. A few years is a long time to store an item.

Comment: @StrongBad I wont fetch any where near to the price I bought them, and I imagine that they will remain newer then the second hand ones available then.

Comment: Don't wrap them in plastic. That exacerbates moisture buildup. Use canvas or something else breathable.

Comment: I expect anything like that left in a UK shed for a few years will rust. The washing machine is likely to have stagnant water retained in it somewhere. The drier may fare a little better.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick hmm thanks for this. Would putting them in the loft (insulated, usually we keep the suitcases there) be better or would they rust there as well?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps, I live on the coast in California where we get a good share of cold and wet weather.my washer and dryer are in a metal shed but I use them weekly. I would think if the units are drained,and off the ground (dirt) they should be fine. You me mentioned wrapping them I believe that be a great idea the only problem I see is if you have critters i.e. Rats squirrels I'm in the mountains and our little critters find places to live in wintertime

Comment: I'd put a can or three of water absorber and some mothballs in there with them. Corrosion due to condensation is the biggest threat, with rodent nests following right after.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to drain the washer , its not two hard If you can lay the discharge hose down on the ground the water may drain out if not pull the hose at the lowest point. I would not be worried about rust these things are living with water and heat or humid air there entire lives if they were going to rust it would have already started. I would be more concerned with mice chewing the wiring.